# What is the intuition behind the definition of a relation

Tags: definition, relations, intuition

I read these days some discrete math and set theory and I found the notion of a "relation".
This definition was proposed in my textbook :

> Let $A$ and $B$ two sets a relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, where the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$ denoted $A \times B$ and defined as follows:
> $$
> A \times B = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \}.
> $$

But I really don't know why it is defined that way.
How we can think of "$\leq$" or "$=$" as relations in $\mathbb{R}$ (set of reals) and
Give other examples if you can.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too vague.  I'm sure your reference has many examples.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) is another source of examples.  I'm sure you can find many more references online.

Comment: The simple definition generalizes naturally to more than two and even infinite amount of sets. That is a very powerful intuitive concept.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, we identify a binary relation with the pairs of things for which it holds. This is an example of an [extensional definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions#Extensional_definition).

This gives us a lot of flexibility: As long as you can define, for any two things $a$ and $b$, whether the relation holds between them, you have a well-defined relation. For example, I can invent an arbitrary relation $R = \{(9, 0)\}$ that holds *only* for the numbers $9$ and $0$. I don't even have to give it a name: The relation is already defined by what pairs of things it holds for.

Another example of extensionality arises when saying what [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) are equal. The [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) effectively says that sets are identified by the things they contain.

Comment: Related reading: https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/HsznWM9A7NiuGsp28/extensions-and-intensions

Answer (score 1):

Having a subset of $S\subseteq A\times B$ allows us to say for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ that $a\sim b$ if the pair $(a,b)\in S.$ For example if we start with the subset
$$
S=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}: a\le b\}
$$

then the pair $(a,b)\in S$ exactly when $a\le b.$

Answer (score 0):

A relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ is defined as a subset of the direct product of two sets. It means that two elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ are related, i.e. $aRb.$ It is the most general concept to bring two objects into a relation of one another. E.g.
$$
R:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\,|\,x=y^2 \}
$$
is a relation because e.g. $(4,2)\, , \,(4,-2)\in R$ or $4R2\, , \,4R(-2).$ it is the "root function" $y=\pm \sqrt{x}.$ However, as there are two values assinged to one $x,$ it is not really a function. It is a relation: one number is the square of the other. To be a function we need to have a single related value, here $y=+\sqrt{x}$ or $y=-\sqrt{x},$ but not both at the same time. E.g. the relation for $y=+\sqrt{x}$ would be
$$
F:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\,|\,x=y^2 \}
$$
Hence every function is a relation, $(4,2)\in F$ and $(4,2)\in R$, but not the other way round since $(4,-2)\in R$ but $(4,-2)\not\in F.$

Especially important relations are equivalence relations such as $"=".$ We have e.g. $2=\dfrac{6}{3}=\dfrac{-8}{-4}=\ldots$ Different quotients are related if they represent the same number.

More generally, equivalence relations $R$ are reflexive $(a,a)\in R,$ symmetric $(a,b)\in R\Rightarrow (b,a)\in R $ and transitive $(a,b)\in R\wedge (b,c)\in R\Rightarrow (a,c)\in R.$